# Error when loading an ASP.NET MVC Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis-7.5

I developed an asp.net mvc 5 web application using VS 2015 community edition. All things worked perfectly, but a few days ago, Visual studio was unable to load the web project, and the below error message is displayed :

---

error  : The Web Application Project elab is configured to use IIS.  To access local IIS Web sites, you must run Visual Studio in the context of an administrator account. In addition, you must install the following IIS components:  ASP.NET

---

I tried to run VS as "Administrator" but unfortunately due to our organisation security policy, I don't have this privileges.

Is there a way to overcome of this problem ?

Comment: contact your admin

Comment: Switch from running against a local IIS to running against IIS Express

Comment: Is there any way to have admin access only on the IIS service, without having the administrator role ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below solution

1. In the solution explorer, right click on the project and select "Properties"
2. Click on "Web" tab
3. Select **"Use Visual studio development Server"** radio button

The above steps will help you to Switch from  **local IIS to IIS Express** ie Visual studio development Server

**Note :** In the same way you can switch back to use local iis at any time you want, but that requires an administration privilege

Comment: Visual studio is unable to load the asp.net mvc application, so is not possible to get the "Properties" windows. furthermore, even if i switched to the iis express, i have the same issues about lack of privileges.